# Return 1-Element Array as Element Type

Tags: julia

If I create a `Vector` of integers

```
a = Vector(1:3)
```

and I index one element it has the type of the element

```
typeof(a[3])
Int64
```

but if I index one element with a range object it has the type Array

```
typeof(a[3:3])
Vector{Int64}
```

How can I make sure that in case of only one element, the element is returned and not the array. The reason is that I want to send the indexed Vector to a function and depending on the type a different method is called.

Answer (score 3):

### Why is this happening?

So here's the problem, when you call `a[3]`
you're actually calling `getindex(a, 3)`
which has the signature `getindex(::AbstractArray, ::Integer)`. 
Your second example is dispatched to a different function, though- `getindex(::AbstractArray, ::UnitRange)`. The behavior of these two functions is different- although they both give what I would expect to see out.

For contrast, both python lists and numpy arrays have the exact same behavior, but it works easier for numpy because numpy doesn't enforce an equal number of dimensions for broadcasting.

### What can you do?

First idea: conditional branching using `length`

```
a = # ...
return length(a) == 1 ? func(a[1]) : func(a)
```

Note you can use `only(a)` instead of `a[1]` if you're on at least Julia 1.3.

Second idea: if you're programmatically indexing into vector, you could check if the two indices are equal

```
i = # ... the first index
j = # ... the second index
return i == j ? func(a[i]) : func(a[i:j])
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but are you maybe looking for `eltype`?

```
julia> eltype(a[3])
Int64

julia> eltype(a[3:3])
Int64
```

EDIT: Reading @Miles Lucas's answer I see a different interpretation of your question. In this case, the `only` function might be helpful:

```
julia> only(a[3])
3

julia> only(a[3:3])
3
```

Note that this errors if you index with a range longer than 1.

Comment: Where is `only` coming from? It tells me `UndefVarError: only not defined`

Comment: It's in version 1.3 or 1.4.

Comment: I'm in "Version 1.3.1 (2019-12-30)" and it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I see now that it was introduced in version 1.4. If you update now, you will get the new 1.4.1, which was just released.